# How to convert an array of arrays presented as a string into array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have a web request with query like this

```
?arr=[1,[2,3,[4],5],6]&depth=2
```

I need this arr to convert into aray (query param is presented as string).

This is an array of arrays and till this moment I don't have better idea rather than implment own parser for it.

I considered `JSON.parse()`, `Array.from()` and `Object.values()`

**Update:**

I considered JSON.parse(). The output is `1,2,3,4,5,6` when I need `[1,[2,3,[4],5],6]`

I use `express`, so the arr I obtain as `req.query.arr`

This is a method

```
app.get('/flatten', function(req, res, next) {

    var arr = JSON.parse(req.query.arr);
    var depth = req.query.depth;

    // convert param into 

    console.log("Type: " + typeof(arr));

    console.log("Incoming params: " + arr + " Is array " + Array.isArray(arr) + " " + depth );

    var result = {result: subject.flatten(arr, depth)};

    res.send(result);
    res.end();
})
```

If you need code here is a [repo](https://github.com/Gelassen/js-interviews/tree/master/flatten%20func)

Does JS provide simpler approach?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: What did you actually try and what happened with those attempts?

Comment: Use [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) constructor to convert it to a key-value pair and then use `JSON.parse(paramObject.get("arr"))` to get the array

Comment: Please take a look on updated post. I shared more details

Comment: Using a method named `flatten()` seems suspicious. Doesn't `arr` contain the expected nested array?

Comment: Nope, I have to transform initial arrays of arrays into single aray or arrays of arrays depends on depth param like [1,2,3,[4],5,6] for depth 1. I already have a function, the final point is link it to web request where I have issue with this converting incoming param into array

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly valid for parsing as [JSON](https://json.org/) string.

```js
var string = '?arr=[1,[2,3,[4],5],6]&depth=2',
    data = string.slice(1).split('&').reduce((r, s) => {
        var [key, value] = s.split('=');
        r[key] = JSON.parse(value);
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Please take a look on updated post. I shared more details.

Comment: After running your code, I see it too.. I will need to go deeper with it

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.parse()` is the simplest approach you can get. Since it will take care of nested arrays and objects as well.

```js
var str = "[1,[2,3,[4],5],6]";
console.log(JSON.parse(str));
```

Comment: Please take a look on updated post. I shared more details

Comment: Updated the answer with a snippet. I'm guessing the issue lies with parsing the query param, because `JSON.parse` would work, as in this snippet. Are you getting the value in the exact same string format as you mentioned?

Comment: I obtain param from query. It is not an array, it is string (you can see in code above how I evaluate it). Indeed, seems issues come from obtaining this param

Comment: I believe the issue is with the query params parsed. Can you add a middleware `app.use(bodyParser.json());` on your express app and then try the same approach?
`const bodyParser = require('body-parser');` should be the import.

Comment: You can validate your express code with this repl - https://repl.it/repls/VividLemonchiffonProcedures

Comment: I already did this. Let me put code on github to let you play with it if you would like to go deeper with this question

Comment: Here is it https://github.com/Gelassen/js-interviews/tree/master/flatten%20func

Comment: Your repo code worked perfectly fine. Just separate the variable `arr` in the logs in line 35 and 37 (app.js) 
Have the variable logged in a separate line as `console.log(arr);` and you'll see that it is an array.

Comment: I believe the failure to get expected response has to do with your other functions.

Comment: I ended up to write own parser, you might check it in the code.